# Yet another "detached entity passed to persist" Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following database model:

```
A| 1..* ------ 0..1 | B
```

with the following entities:

A:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "B", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private B singleB;
```

B:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "B")
private List<A> aList;
```

Then I'm trying to create a new B for A:

```
...
b.prepareCreate(existingA);
dao.create();
...
```

Methods:

```
public void prepareCreate(A existingAObject) {
    b = new B();
    b.setAList(new ArrayList());
    b.getAList.add(existingAObject);
}

public void create() {
    getEntityManager().persist(b);
}
```

And then it throws the exception. Long story short: I want to create a new B for an existing A, but Hibernate is trying to create a new A. I think it is an annotation problem but not sure how.

UPDATE:

Show us how you get your existingAObject. - from the database (existingA = em.find(id));

And also realize that if you want to save the association between A and B, then A.singleB must be set, since it's the owning side of the association. 
- Tried that and still get the exception

And show us the complete code of the B entity: what is its ID? How is it generated?

pretty straightforward:

```
public class B implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "B")
    private List<A> aList;


    @XmlTransient
    public List<A> getAList() {
        return eventos;
    }

    public void setAList(List<A> aList) {
        this.aList= aList;
    }
```

}

Comment: Show us how you get your existingAObject. And also realize that if you want to save the association between A and B, then `A.singleB` must be set, since it's the owning side of the association. And show us the complete code of the B entity: what is its ID? How is it generated?

Comment: Ok, completed with missing code.

Comment: Is the `B.id` field null when you call `persist()`?

Comment: Yes it is, as it's intended to create a new B and then persist the A entity with the newly created B.

Comment: Your code doesn't persist A. It persists B. Show us the actual code, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: But it's trying to. Let's say the A entity is an Album and the B entity is a Photo. My view shows a datatable with the photos in a specific album. Then I right click the table row (using rich:contexmenu) and select an option called "Add a new Photo". The `photo.prepareCreate(selectedAlbum)` method is called, wich performs `Photo newPhoto = new Photo()` , `newPhoto.setAlbum(selectedAlbum)` and `album.add(newPhoto)`. (continues)

Comment: I select the image file and click a commandButton that fires the `photoBean.create()` method. As result of this method, the exception "detached entity passed to persist: com.photoalbum.Album". If I set album.id to null, it creates a new Album in the database, with the newly created Photo. The `photoBean.create()` is: `getEntityManager().persist(entity)`; Sorry I can't post the actual code.

Comment: If you can't post the actual code, and if the code you post is different from the actual code, then how can we help? Hire a consultant. Or realize that your code doesn't contain any secret. You either persist the album (i.e. A) and not the Photo (i.e. B), which is not what your question shows, or you have a cascade on B.A, which your question doesn't show either. You can't persist a detached entity. If you have a cascade, then remove it. And you should probably use merge() anyway. But it's impossible to tell without knowing what the actual code does.

Comment: I took snippets from the actual code, just changed the names, I really can't post it all, I know how this is important, but I'm sorry and thankful for your help. Everything is just like its in the question. There's no cascade but I do have tried with it. Thanks.

Comment: The key is in the first comment by JB Nizet, that a.singleB is the "owning side" of the relation. If you've already got a persistent A, and you want to "move" it "into" an new not-yet-persistent B, then you've got to make the new B persistent (without anything in its collection of A's) and *then* set a.setSingleB(b) and add the A to b's collection (as far as persistence is concerned, only a.setSingleB matters, but you'll still want to add a to b's collection)

Comment: Thanks Tommy Knowlton and JB Nizet, I have changed the code to do as told and it works. I think it's impossible to cascade from the creation of B to update of A, wich was what I intended to do